# How to follow dev branch lagging behind master branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

I have more projects and branches like dev, feature, bug and master etc.
Over time, there are differences between branches and it becomes difficult to follow them.

Is it possible to see branch statuses in a table. For example,
dev, master **uptodate status**,
**last commit**,
**waiting pull request**
who approved etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in the following menu

[image: Menu: Repos > Branches]

It looks like this:
[image: Overview]

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/manage-your-branches?view=azure-devops